# Get hash value Rails / Chart JS / Google Chart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-visualization, chart.js

I'm developing a form generator, I'm asking users and I want to make charts for each question.

For each question I'm using the count method :

```
         @pollsQuestion4 = @polls.where(question_id: 4).group("nom")
         @pollsQuestion5 = @polls.where(question_id: 5).group("nom")
```

(In the future I'm gonna loop to make it for each question in my form)

With the .count method I have this result :

## Controller

```
<%= @polls4.count %>
```

## View

```
{"Bleu"=>4, "blanc"=>2, "rouge"=>1}
```

How can I get the values 4,2,1,etc.. to populate my data field in a ChartJS script or Google Chart script ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) applies the SQL COUNT to your query, resulting in something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
AS count_all, "polls"."nom"
AS polls_nom
FROM "polls"
WHERE "polls"."question_id" = $1
GROUP BY "polls"."nom"
```

And you get a Hash object, so you can access their values iterating like usual in a Hash:

```
@pollsQuestion4.each do |key, value|
  ...
end
```

If otherwise you want only the values, then you can use [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
@pollsQuestion4.values
```

And then you get an array.

Comment: Thank you ! @SebastianPalma

Comment: Yes I obtained what I was looking for @sebastianPalma

Answer (score 1):

You can return the values of a hash as an array using `hash.values`. 
I'm not familiar with chart.js particularly, but based on [this example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) it looks like you just need this data as a Javascript array; so in your view I'd expect something like

```
data: <%= hash.values.to_json %>
```

in a js.erb file to work, rendered using the `formats: :js` option.